# Asserting REST response in StringReader format

Tags: json, rest, testing, groovy, automation

I need to assert a response which is in the java.io.StringReader  format. .  I am able to get the correct response as {"isValid": false} when I use response.data. But when I try to assert this response using

```
response.data == '{"isValid": false}'
```

I  get the below error.

```
Condition not satisfied:

response.data == '{"isValid": false}'
|        |    |
|        |    false
|            java.io.StringReader@35636217
groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseDecorator@5e4fa1da
```

How do I parse the StringReader format.

Comment: Please provided some context.

Comment: Was that the full json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parse(response.data) jsonSlurper == [virtualCard:false]

Answer (score 0):

How about checking `isValid` as `false`?

```
assert !response.data.isValid, 'isValid is not matching the expected value'
```

EDIT: based on OP's comment.

```
def str = '''{"isValid": false}​​​​'''
def value = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(str)​.isValid​

assert response.data == value, 'isValid is not matching the expected value'
```

Comment: {"isValid": false} is the response which is of the class java.io.StringReader . I am using spock framework to do the assertion. !response.data.isValid does not work.

Comment: Can you show what does `response.data` value is? and you are comparing with `json`, right?

Comment: Please check the edited answer to see if that helps.

Comment: I figured out. def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parse(response.data) jsonSlurper == [virtualCard:false] Thanks for your help!